# ANOVA for analysis of calculated probabilities

Tags: r, probability, anova

I am working with infection and mortality numbers in plants. I have the raw numbers and calculated probabilities based on the sample size for both.

Initially I thought I needed to use the raw data in a GLM model and the predict function in R to graph and analyze the data. However, a member of my lab group thought this was incorrect and that a simple analysis of calculated probabilities with ANOVA would be more appropriate, and more powerful.

Is there any reason why it would not be appropriate to utilize ANOVA to analyze calculated probabilities?

I have attached a screenshot of some similar data to give an idea

Thanks in advance for any input you can provide
[image: Sample data from exel]

Answer (score 1):

From a practical perspective, ANOVA is not a good model choice when the outcome variable is a probability. This is because ANOVA assumes that the outcome variable follows a normal distribution - not the case for probabilities. I'm happy to explain more of the technical stuff if you'd like.

Picking a more suitable type of analysis is a matter of what you'd like to *explain* with your study.

- Do you want to determine if mortality is associated with one or two other variables? You'd want a Chi-Squared Test.
- Do you want to build a model that explains the nature of the
  relationship between some set of explanatory variables (like Month or
  Infection Status) and mortality outcomes for your plants? Then you
  would want to go the GLM route

Again, I'm happy to go into more detail and help you through the analysis work.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wanna build a model that predict the mortality according to the explanation variable.

Let's take this situation: you have got fellings that climate conditions inherent in each month cause health effects of the plant, leading to infection and death. Right ?

So you collect the data of the weather and humidity from every months and apply some regration model upon your data.

Whether you want to calculate a kind of probability of mortality, for example, you should use probit model. But I can't see on your database any explanatory variable (or independent variable).

I see you got the outcomes from the research as numbers of infected and number of not infected. But I can't see the number (independenet variable) that problably causes those infections, like either weather or humidity or even number of plagues etc.

Seccond to your database you have only "outcomes". So what can you do with them What about the ANOVA?

Since you have only "outcomes" you can compare whether there are statistically significant differences that "allow" you state that in July the plants become more vulnerable and infected than in September and not just because you first clapped the eyes on that table and guessed that there is a difference.

So is that what you can do with ANOVA :)